# Chess Engine - Represent bitboard in 32bit Nasm

Tags: assembly, 32bit-64bit, chess

I'm trying to write a chess engine in 32bit nasm. I read up on bit boards and I want to represent the board using bit boards, however the fact i'm working with 32bit registers is an inconvenience. What I did is divide each bit board into 32bit sections. But would it be better to just define qWords and split them up on the fly?

This is my board data section

```asm
                    ;bitboards for white
    whiteLowerPawns     dd  0xff00
    whiteLowerBishops   dd  0x24
    whiteLowerKnights   dd  0x42
    whiteLowerCastles   dd  0x81
    whiteLowerQueens    dd  0x8
    whiteLowerKing      dd  0x10

    whiteUpperPawns     dd  0x0
    whiteUpperBishops   dd  0x0
    whiteUpperKnights   dd  0x0
    whiteUpperCastles   dd  0x0
    WhiteUpperQueens    dd  0x0
    WhiteUpperKing      dd  0x0

                    ;bitboards for black
    blackUpperPawns     dd  0xff0000
    blackUpperBishops   dd  0x24000000
    blackUpperKnights   dd  0x42000000
    blackUpperCastles   dd  0x81000000
    blackUpperQueens    dd  0x8000000
    blackUpperKing      dd  0x10000000

    blackLowerPawns     dd  0x0
    blackLowerBishops   dd  0x0
    blackLowerKnights   dd  0x0
    blackLowerCastles   dd  0x0
    blackLowerQueens    dd  0x0
    blackLowerKing      dd  0x0
```

Comment: Frankly writing a chess engine in assembler is not a good idea. You waste your time writing assembler code instead of creating fast algorithms.

Comment: And writing one that uses bitboards in 32-bit assembler is an even worse idea.  A C compiler spends a lot of time manipulating the hi- and lo- 32-bit words of the bitboard when a simple operation is applied to it.  It's normal to write some functions in assembler but not the whole thing.

Comment: Ok yeah I sort of figured that, however this is a semi-large project for one of my university classes so I don't have much of choice. I did move to 64bit asm so that has helped, also I'm not trying to make the most perfect or lean chess engine, just something semi barebones that can play at maybe average human level.

Comment: I finished this project. I changed to 64bit assembly, much easier to work with since the bitboards are 64bits wide.

Comment: May I please have your source code?

Comment: https://github.com/CrSeth/x86ChessEngine

Sorry for the super late reply. It was a class project so it is not a 100% working engine and some things were done very inefficiently due to time restraints.